# Need some help finding a suitable $a$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function

$$ g_a (x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^a\sin ({1\over x}) & x \neq 0 \\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$

I would like to find $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $g_a$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ but $g_a'$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$. I start by computing the derivative:

$$ g_a' (x) = 
\begin{cases}
ax^{a-1}\sin ({1\over x}) - x^{a-2}\cos ({1\over x})& x \neq 0 \\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$

I take condition 1, $g_a$ differentiable on $\mathbb R$, and it implies that $g_a'$ must be defined everywhere and therefore $a>2$ (because of the second term with the $a-2$ in the exponent). My problem starts when I'm trying to make $g_a'$ unbounded on $[0,1]$. Since the $\sin$ and $\cos$ are both bounded it seems obvious that the only way to make it unbounded is to have $x < 2$ in order to get $x$ into the denominator of a fraction. But this would contradict the existence of the derivative at $0$. What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $a\in\mathbb R $, the function $g_a$ is differentiable for every $x\ne 0$.
At $x=0$, the limit
$$
\frac{g_a(h)-g_a(0)}{h}=\frac{h^a\sin (1/h)}{h}
$$
exists if and only if $a>1$. So $g_a$ is differentiable everywhere if and only if $a>1$.
In such case its derivative is equal to
$$ g_a' (x) = 
\begin{array}{ccc}
ax^{a-1}\sin (x^{-1}) - x^{a-2}\cos (x^{-1})&\text{if} &x \neq 0, \\
0 & \text{if}& x=0,
\end{array}$$
and $g'_a$ is unbounded in $[0,1]$ if and only if $a< 2$.

Therefore, $g_a$ is differentiable with unbounded derivative iff $a\in(1,2)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try for example $a=3/2$. You will find that $g_a(x)$ is differentiable at $0$. (Use the *definition* of the derivative to do this. The derivative is not continuous at $0$.)  After you have done the calculation, it will be clear what $a$ will work.

Comment: I did the computation with $a=3/2$ and it is easy to verify that it is differentiable at $0$. What I still can't do is verify that $g_{3/2}'$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$. It is most likely obvious but I would greatly appreciate a hint. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Ignore my comment I think I figured it out!

Comment: You have made the calculation yourself. To quote what you wrote, with $a=3/2$, we have for $x\ne 0$ that $g_a'(x)=(3/2)x^{1/2}\sin(1/x)- x^{-1/2}\cos(1/x)$. Let $x=1/(2n\pi)$, where $n$ is huge. The first part of $g_a'(x)$ is near $0$. The second part is exactly $-\sqrt{2n\pi}$, big negative.  We can also find positive $x$ near $0$ where the derivative is big positive, anything we want.