# Continuity and differentiability of $x^a\sin ({1\over x}) $ at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity, solution-verification

Consider the function

$$ g_a (x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^a\sin ({1\over x}) & x \neq 0 \\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$

I am looking to determine for which $a$ the map $g_a$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ with $g_a'$ continuous but not differentiable at zero. Please can you check my work?

From [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665958/need-some-help-finding-a-suitable-a) I already know that $a>1$ for $g_a$ to be differentiable.

The map $g_a'(x) = ax^{a-1}\sin ({1\over x}) - x^{a-2}\cos ({1\over x})$ is continuous at $0$ of and only if both exponents are $> 0$ which holds if and only if $a>2$. It remains to be determined for which $a$ this map is not differentiable at zero. To this end consider the right limit:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} { ax^{a-1}\sin ({1\over x}) - x^{a-2}\cos ({1\over x}) \over x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} ax^{a-2}\sin ({1\over x}) - x^{a-3}\cos ({1\over x}) $$

This limit does not converge to $0$ if and only if $a \le 3$. Hence $g_a$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and with $g_a'$ continuous but not differentiable at $0$ for $a \in (2,3)$.

Comment: It's $a \in (2,3]$. Apart from that, it's correct.